# PyQt make QFrame appear on top of another widget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

So my application's main part consists of a QFrame which contains 2 other QFrames (left one for a menu, right for the content of the current page selected) I made the layout in QtDesigner as follows:

[image: Layout]

I added an animation for opening/closing the menu on the left, making the QPushButton texts visible when open, hiding them when closed (Only the icon shows in that case) by increasing the QFrame's width.

```
    def ToggleMenu(self):
        width = self.ui.frame_left_menu.width()
        defaultWidth = 70
        toggleWidth = 200
        
        if width == defaultWidth:
            toggleWidth = 200
            self.ui.frame_content_right.lower()
            self.ui.frame_left_menu.raise_()
        else:
            toggleWidth = 70
            self.ui.frame_left_menu.lower()
            self.ui.frame_content_right.raise_()
        
        self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.ui.frame_left_menu, b"minimumWidth")
        self.animation.setDuration(300)
        self.animation.setStartValue(width)
        self.animation.setEndValue(toggleWidth)
        self.animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutQuart)
        self.animation.start()
```

`ToggleMenu()` is called when the user clicks on the menu button (thats outside of `frame_center`, increasing/decreasing its width.

When opening the menu, its width is increased, thus pushing the right QFrame along, making the available space smaller for actual content.

I would like to be able to make it so the menu is displayed above the content QFrame when opened. I tried calling raise_() and lower() on open/close, but that doesn't seem to change anything, I think that is because they are not overlapping to begin with, given the layout above.

I would like to avoid creating the layout at runtime if possible. How could I solve this?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Added more details to the question.

Comment: From the look of it, that frame is added to a layout. If you resize a widget that is part of a layout (like you're doing with the animation), the result is that all other widgets on the same layout get resized. For a normal toggle animation (that completely hides the "hovering" widget), that wouldn't be a problem, as it's enough to remove the widget from the layout of its parent, but from what you're describing things become more complex, especially if you don't know how layouts work. Unfortunately, since your example is just minimal but *not* reproducible, we can't help you more.